# OnKeydown for "-" does not get fired in Delphi 7 application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, onkeydown

We are using Delphi 7 enterprise edition, application is build on windows XP, testing on both Windows XP and Windows 7.

In an application we maintain, something strange is happening. For some reason hitting the "-" key (qwerty layout, between "0" and "=" keys on top) does not register at all.

We checked in the OnKeyDown of the edit we found it with, the OnKeyDown of the form (with and without key preview) and even the ProcessMessage routine, but the event for this key never reaches the application.
We get the same results for OnKeyPress.

Yes, the "-" key on the numpad DOES work. Also, this behavior is only seen in this application, but if we create a new application with only the OnKeyDown of the default form in unit1.pas implemented. it does work.

So somehow we managed to tell the application to properly ignore this one key.
Does anyone have an idea how this could be (un)done?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in 'StdWndProc' in classes.pas with condition `(Message = WM_CHAR) and (WParam = Ord('-'))` and trace from there.

Comment: Only you can answer this question since only you have the code. Use the age old trick of stripping out code until the behaviour changes. Then look at what you last removed.

Comment: @Sertac StdWndProc is called after ProcessMessage, so it does not show up there either. Also, using SpyXX, we can see that the WM_CHAR for "-" doesn't show up.

Comment: @deColaman - The message loop can be overtaken by any piece of code. So `Application.ProcessMessage` might not be called, but a message retrieved from the message queue *must* be dispatched for application to work correctly. That's why I proposed `StdWndProc`. The fact that the character message is not delivered to the window procedure means the message is not posted at all. I cannot guess why..

Comment: .. the last part should read - ..not posted (WM_KEYDOWN), or not translated (WM_CHAR), or not dispatched (some message loops eat some messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David's comment is on the right track; You can (with version control) strip back the app until you understand what is going on. However I think that you need to understand the following concepts as well:

1. OnKeyDown event in a form is not the only place that keyboard shortcuts could go.  You should find out where else it's going to, which is why Sertac's comment is there.
2. It is possible that something OUTSIDE your application is trapping that keyboard key (although this is more common with Control or Alt + Key combinations).
3. It is possible that something inside your form, or elsewhere in your application is grabbing that key and consuming it.
4. There is a good article here about [KeyPreview](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/keyboard_events.htm), you need to understand that too.

Comment: 1) `ProcessMessage` comes before `StdWndProc` (after Application,Run according to the `callstack`) 2) Unlikely, as all other applications do capture it properly 3) If that were true, it would have to go through `ProcessMessage` first right? 4) Read and already understand it.

Comment: @deColaman - See the comment I commented to the question for point (1) and (3).

Comment: after stripping the code for several days, I found that a separator in the menu bar had the shortcut key '-'.

It is still strange that the key never registered in any keydown / press events at all (nor in StdWndProc btw.)